# Can't parse html correctly / empty body after parsing

Tags: xpath, scrapy, css-selectors, selector

I am facing an odd problem. I im trying to parse the following html:

[image]

The problem is that when I do

`response.xpath('//div//section//div[@id="hiring-candidate-app"]')[0].extract()`

I only get

`'<div id="hiring-candidate-app"></div>'`

instead of all the content under `hiring-candidate-app`.

I would like to get, for instance, `inside-content`, but it looks like I am not even getting that in the response. This webpage requires to be logged in, which I am.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @wp78de I wasn't able to try what you suggested, I solved it using selenium. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Xpath is grabbing the right thing. But your issue might have to do with the '[0]' part of the call. I would remove that to get the full content of the div.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the elements in question sit on an `<iframe>`, and therefore live in a different context. You need to activate or switch to the context of the iframe, eg. using JavaScript to interact with an iframe and the document inside of it, e.g.

```js
//Note: Assigning document.domain is forbidden for sandboxed iframes, i.e. on stacksnippets
//document.domain = "https://stacksnippets.net";

var ifrm = document.getElementById("myFrame");
// reference to iframe's window
//var win = ifrm.contentWindow;
// reference to document in iframe
var doc = ifrm.contentDocument ? ifrm.contentDocument : ifrm.contentWindow.document;
// reference an element via css selector in iframe
//var form = doc.getElementById('body > div > div.message');
// reference an element via xpat in iframe
var xpathResult = doc.evaluate("/html/body/div/div[1]", doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

```html
<iframe id="myFrame" src="https://stacksnippets.net" style="height:380px;width:100%"></iframe>
```

However, as you can see when you run the snipped, cross-document interactions are only possible if the documents have the same origin. There are other, more involved methods like the [postMessage](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/postmessage/) method that provide the means of interacting cross-domain.